# Salvar arquivos de audio manipulados mantendo o nome original

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou utilizando um algoritmo que encontrei para realizar a limpeza de ruído de arquivos WAV, porém preciso rodar este algoritmo em mais de mil arquivos e preciso manter o nome original do arquivo que será salvo em uma outra pasta.

Criei um diretório com os áudios originais, e rodei o algoritmo no laço `for` abaixo, mas estou com dificuldades para usar o nome original do arquivo na hora de salvar.

```
data_dir = '/Users/Sergio/Desktop/Macuco/WAV1'
audio_files = glob(data_dir + '/*.wav')

len(audio_files)

for file in range(0, len(audio_files), 1):

    data, rate = librosa.load(audio_files[file])
    noisy_part = data[round(len(data)*0.99):len(data)]
    reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=noisy_part, verbose=True)

    data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, len(data))
    scaled = np.int16(reduced_noise/np.max(np.abs(data)) * 32768)
    wavfile.write('/Users/Sergio/Desktop/Macuco/WAV1/filtered.wav', rate, scaled)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O arquivo de som original está sendo lido enquanto a conversão está feita, então, não é possível usar o mesmo nome para o resultado. Você tem que usar um nome diferente.

O que você pode fazer é gerar um arquivo temporário, e, assim que ele for completamente gravado, remover o arquivo original e renomear o arquivo temporário, para que fique com o mesmo nome do original:

```
wavfile.write(audio_files[file] + '.tmp', rate, scaled)
os.remove(audio_files[file])
os.rename(audio_files[file] + '.tmp', audio_files[file])
```

Comment: Adaptei sua ideia para inclusão da marca '_filtrado' junto ao nome do arquivo original, conforme abaixo. 

    wavfile.write(audio_files[file].replace('.wav', '_filtrado.wav'), rate, scaled)

Answer (score 0):

Ou também você poderia criar um diretório dentro da pasta principal para armazenar os arquivos analisados e em seguida salvar o arquivo já na extensão final nessa pasta.

Só precisaria adicionar um `os.mkdir(f"{data_dir}/WAV_filtrados")` no início do seu código e ao invés de salvar na pasta principal salvar dentro desta pasta.